# Yet another anonymous access question

Tags: anonymous-authentication

It seems like anonymous access to SP lists is an excruciating pain for all besides the security reasons. My boss wants a single form in the list be public and redirect to a thank you page once an anonymous user submits the form. I managed the redirection and submission successfully. I enabled anonymous access to that particular list. When an anonymous user submits the form, SP gives the following error instead of redirecting to a thank you page.

***The data source control failed to execute the insert command.***

Is it a worklow issue since the list used to be private?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: Never tried it but worked for one of my colleague. Might loose some running instances of workflow**

Go to Settings > List Settings

Under Permission and Management, select Workflow Settings

Find the name of workflow there, and then click on Remove a workflow

Mark all instances to Remove

Try re-attaching workflow to the list. Try initiating again and hopefully it should work.

Comment: didnt work :(
what about lists with no workflows.